# Do I need to import NumPy before importing pandas or can I use pandas by itself?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know pandas is built on NumPy, and my class examples also always include import NumPy first. I'm just not sure if this is a required step or a "just in case" type situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to import numpy before importing pandas. For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series(range(10))

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64
```

The reason that it is often imported along with pandas is that you often will create an array using numpy which is then passed to pandas.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'np' is not defined` (because of the reference to `np.nan`) when I try this. Changing it to `pd.np.nan` works.

Comment: Doh! Yeah I copied that from the pandas docs and forgot I had my PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable set to automatically import numpy.